# Extract non-repeated lists from a list of lists based on a criteria on a common element in all lists

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to extract non-repeated lists from a list of lists based on a criteria on a common element in all lists? For example if I have the following list of list:

```
list_lists = [['a', [1,2]], ['b', [2,5]], ['c', [1,2]], ['d', [2,5]], ['e', [2,6]]]
```

Let's assume that my criteria to call a list unique is the last element in that list. So, since [2,6] is repeated once then ['e', [2,6]] is the only element that is unique and I can say:

```
list_of_unique = [['e', [2,6]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive solution that firstly comes to mind

```
list_lists = [['a', [1,2]], ['b', [2,5]], ['c', [1,2]], ['d', [2,5]], ['e', [2,6]]]
counter = {}

for i in range(len(list_lists)):
    last = tuple(list_lists[i][-1])

    if last not in counter:
        counter[last] = 1, i
    else:
        counter[last] = counter[last][0] + 1, i

print([list_lists[i] for c, i in counter.values() if c == 1])
```